# How to handle .net dll event in a web page?

Tags: .net, web

I have a .net dll that generates an event. The event always returns a number. I want to dynamicaly view the number on web page, updating every time the value changes. How can I acomplish that? What should I use? html, ajax, javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which technology your web site is using ? Asp .Net ?

If you have server code listening for the event, you could expose a web service to query that number using javascript periodically

Another way is to use SignalR or websockets

But we need to know how your pages are build first to give you good advices